# iPhone deselect row after delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I was wondering if anyone was aware of a way to deselect a table view after a delay?

I am using the `deselectRowAtIndexPath` method.  I just want the highlighting to show up for a second before deselecting it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to do that using `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];`

Another way to do this would be:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(deselect:) withObject:self afterDelay:0.33];
```

and then create a method `deselect` that calls `deselectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: +1 this is what i would use, although according to what you have there, the `deselect` method should take a parameter (you're passing `self` as a parameter), which means it'd be called `deselect:`, at the least.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to accomplish is: Tap a row, see highlight, highlight goes away you can:

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
//after you do whatever your doing when a row is selected
UITableViewCell *cell [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell setSelected:NO];
```

This will produce the effect you're looking for if I haven't misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(deselect:) withObject:self afterDelay:0.33];
```

#### Swift version:

To add a slight delay when deselecting a tableview cell, you need to add the following to `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.33) {
   self.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```