# How to add a slight delay before triggering didSelectRowAt action and deselecting the tabelview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

Edit:
*I didn't realize that it is the Animates (in segue in storyboard) and animated in pushViewController() which does the job.*

How to smooth transition to next view when we tap on a row in table view. I want to achieve similar smooth transitioning effect as Apple's Settings app. Right now my transition happens immediately as soon as row is touched.

On Apple's settings app when you tap on a row on Settings menu, it first highlights the row then smoothly transitions to next view. This is what I want to achieve.

I've searched but can't find any relevant solution. Any help?

Following is my code for row select

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
    //.....
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at `UINavigationController?` and `pushViewController(_ :animated:)`?

Comment: You'll need to post the code you're using to perform the transition.

Comment: I've updated my question with relevant code.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I believe he wants the animation that `UINavigationController` provides.

Comment: @ParthTamane. Ok so it's the UINavigationController which provides this animation. What if we don't use UINavigationController? Can the same be achieved in this case?

Comment: I think so. I believe you can set the presentation animation type from storyboard.

Comment: @ParthTamane Thanks.

Comment: Check my answer. I think you need the push style. But you can see which one looks best.

Comment: If you're using `animated: false` then you're telling the system you don't want an animation. Just set it to `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the presentation style. So click on your segue in the storyboard. Then select `Kind` as `Push` from the dropdown in `Attributes Inspector` on the right side.

[image]

Also, to present it programmatically, you need to set an identifier in the first text field in `Attributes Inspector`. After that in your `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` add this.

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
```

If you want a delayed action then you can use `asyncAfter`, like [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034044/iphone-deselect-row-after-delay).

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.33) {
   self.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that Animates has to be selected too. It's the animation property which has this effect. I didn't realize it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: NP! :) "Just wanted to add that Animates has to be selected too" is this another property in the attributes inspector?

Comment: Also, could you accept the answer if this worked for you? Thanks :)

Comment: It does work however it doesn't show the same animation effect as Settings app. Settings app has a little more delay before it transitions to the next view. Do you know how to achieve the same level of delay as Settings app?

Comment: Yeah! You need to manually initiate the segue I think. Let me look it up.

Comment: I'm already doing it manually via pushViewController()

Comment: Wait how are you using pushViewController if it's a segue based animation?

Comment: No. I'm not using segue when using pushViewController. It's either segue or pushViewController. In both cases I observe that my apps is quicker than Settings app.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. And what is the source of click? A UIButton or a  TableViewCell?

Comment: It's TableViewCell. Have a look at Apple's Settings app first and try your app to observe the delay after tapping on a row in a table view. I've a feeling that in Settings app there is more delay after tap and before showing next view.

Comment: You are right. The settings app does add a slight delay. Does the `asyncAfter` help? If not I will look into it in few hours.

Comment: I think my updated answer should do exactly what you are looking for! :3 Cheers!

Comment: Np! And thanks for pointing it out. I'll update my didSelect too :)